# Backbone add event

Tags: backbone.js

I have a collection where is has an event that gets fired when a model is added. I have read in the docs where it should have an options parameter but not able to get to it. 
I basically want to find the index the model is at in the collection.
Inside my collection I have this.

```
    initialize: function( ) {
        this.bind( 'add', this.onModelAddedd, this );
    },

    onModelAddedd: function( model, options ){

           console.log("options = ", options);
    }
```

Answer (score 23):

The documentation is a little unclear on this so your confusion is understandable. From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog):

> **Catalog of Events**
>
> Here's a list of all of the built-in events that Backbone.js can fire. You're also free to trigger your own events on Models and Views as you see fit.
>
> - **"add"** (model, collection, options) — when a model is added to a collection.
> - ...

So the second argument to the `add` handler is the collection itself. The ubiquitous `options` that you're looking for is always the last argument so you want this:

```
onModelAddedd: function(model, collection, options) {
    console.log("options = ", options);
}
```

Demo (open your console please): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Das2t/

The final `options` argument is implied to be the last argument throughout the documentation but it isn't explicitly spelled out anywhere.

Comment: after all this time, i still learn new stuff ... didn't know about the options param for those events. thanks mu! :)

Comment: @DerickBailey: That's why we're here, no? I've learned a good chunk of my Backbone, PostgreSQL, Ruby, and CoffeeScript knowledge by answer questions here.

Comment: Wow, I keep the Backbone doc page open all day while writing code, refer to it every day, and I somehow have never seen the "Catalog of Events" section :) Thanks!

Comment: the demo no longer works as the links to the libraries are dead.
i've made a new demo of my own, you can use it: http://jsfiddle.net/Das2t/41/

Comment: Thanks @Roey, I updated the original fiddle with the latest Backbone and Underscore from a CDN.