# uncaught typeerror object has no method 'on' : backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone. I have started developing a web app using Backbone, However, this error has put me off my stride. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my Model Class and Collection:

```
    var tasks = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    default: function() {
    return {
        task : ''
       }}
    });

    var taskslist = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
        model: tasks
    });

    var alltasks = new taskslist();
```

And this is the View Class :

```
    var taskview = Backbone.View.extend({ 
        model: new tasks(),
        tagName: 'div',
        initialize : function() { 
        this.template = _.template($('#temp').html());
    },
    render : function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));  
        return this;
    }
    });



    var alltasksview = Backbone.View.extend ({ 
        model : 'tasks',
        el : $('#box1'),

    initialize : function() {
        this.model.on('add', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.$el.html('');
        _.each(this.model.toArray(), function(tasks, i) {
            self.$el.append(new tasksview({ model:tasks }).render().$el);
            });
        }
    });
```

and in the jQuery document ready function, I listen for a button click this way to add items of that model on click :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

$("#but1").click(function(e) { 

    var task1 =  new tasks({ task : $('#text1').val() });
    alltasks.add(task1);
    console.log(alltasks.toJSON()); 
 });
 });
```

This piece of code throws the subject error. Also, My Backbone version is 1.0.0.

Thank you.

Comment: I think, in model don't have `add` event! maybe you would use 'change' or 'all' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [Catalog of Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog)  the `add` event exists and it should be triggered on your model.

The problem might be in the model, in the above code, looks like that your model is nothing more than a string:

```
....
    model : 'tasks',
    el : $('#box1'),
...
```

which probably has no `add` event. Try to initialize `this.model` correctly and it will work as expected.

Here is a fiddle I found in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875003/backbone-add-event): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Das2t/

Comment: Thank you for the solution akoskm. I got it to work. However, the render function inside the view is not firing, any answers to that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I just fixed it just now.
The problem is that Backbone requires jQuery 1.7 or higher, I replaced jQuery version 1.10 to 1.4.3, this error hasn't occured any more.
If this doesn't work,try to use bind method.